# Svelte and .d.ts generation with rollup

Tags: typescript, svelte, rollup, .d.ts

I am trying to bundle with rollup a library written in svelte/ts. My purpose is of course to produce a `.js` (several for es/umd/...) and a `.d.ts` file.

As an input (source-code) I have :

- .ts files
- .svelte files (using `<script lang="ts">` tag)
- .d.ts files

I tried several .d.ts bundler but all fail at a moment. I tried using them as plugins in my main rollup configuration, to use it in a separate configuration or even as a second command beside rollup, annexed some examples (not exhaustive).

Does anyone already had this bundling successfully done ?

#### nothing

Just using no plugin but specifying `"declaration": true` in `tsconfig.json` will not raise any error but create a .d.ts who

- does not contain the declarations from my source .d.ts
- produce some `export { something } from "./my-source.svelte";` in the output folder who contains only the produced `.js` file.

#### svelte-dts

Raises an exception because, when analysing the `.d.ts` file, the `declaration` property of the file analysis is .... `undefined`

#### rollup-plugin-dts

Will raise an `Export '...' is not defined (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)` on a `export class ...`

#### dts-bundle-generator

Trying to run `dts-bundle-generator` as a separate command: I couldn't find a way for it to take into consideration my source `.d.ts` files, so it complains about undefined types

Comment: I have exact the same challenge!